# Remote Temperature Sensor

Tags: arduino, sensor

I'd like to set up an arduino to remotelet monitor temperature using a wired sensor.  Will wire length come in to play?  For example, if I have 2 sensors 1 with a 10 ft run the other with a 30 foot run, will that work with the same code and components? I guess the short question is how much to I have to worry about resistive losses?

Comment: A example project that reads a couple of temperature sensors and sends them to a mqtt server https://github.com/jsiei97/FunTechHouse_RoomTemperature

Answer (score 4):

If you use a sensor with a digital interface such as the popular 1-Wire type then the wire distance will not affect the temperature accuracy in any major way. Also with 1-Wire sensors it is possible to buss multiple sensors onto a single wire run!!

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what sensor you are using but lets say it is a 10K thermistor like [this one](http://au.element14.com/betatherm/10k3a1b/thermistor-ntc/dp/9707204):

[image]

30 ft of AWG 22 wire has a resistance of about 0.5 Ohms (according to [this site](http://www.cirris.com/testing/resistance/wire.html)). Including the return path that is 1 Ohm. So the resistance of the thermistor will be 1/10000 out, or 0.001%. Given that the manufacturer resistance tolerance is around 0.5% to 0.1% depending on the product, then the extra resistance from the wire won't cause any noticeable error.

Of course if the resistance of the thermistor was much lower it will be affected by the wire resistance, but it would have to be lower than 100 Ohm for a 1% error with 30 ft AWG 22 cable.